# Wrong values in System.Diagnostics.Metrics.Histogram buckets

Tags: c#, histogram, prometheus, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm learning telemetry metrics for sending them to `Prometheus`.

I wrote a C# console application (.NET 7).

I want to meter the ping time and save values to a histogram with custom boundaries.
Here is a histogram configuration code:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;

var meter = new Meter("MeterUsing");
var pingHistogram = meter.CreateHistogram<int>("ping", "ms", "The ping time");
var meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
    .AddMeter(meter.Name)
    .AddView(pingHistogram.Name, 
        new ExplicitBucketHistogramConfiguration { Boundaries = new double[] { 100, 200, 500, 1000 } })
    .Build();
```

Then I record values:

```
pingHistogram.Record(rand.Next(30, 2000));
```

I push it to the  `OpenTelemetry Collector`. Then `Prometheus` scrapes data.
When I open the collector metrics endpoints, I see the following:

```
# HELP ping The ping time
# TYPE ping histogram
ping_bucket{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing",le="100"} 2
ping_bucket{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing",le="200"} 5
ping_bucket{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing",le="500"} 13
ping_bucket{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing",le="1000"} 23
ping_bucket{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing",le="+Inf"} 64
ping_sum{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing"} 69801
ping_count{instance="280616b2-1c17-426a-9cf0-f33183ef7dfc",job="MeterUsing"} 64
```

It looks strange for me. I expected to see in buckets a count of values which suits a bucket range.
But I see that `ping_count` value equals `ping_bucket{le="+Inf"}`. Counts in buckets are kind of ordered by `le`.
I understand that it looks like a percentile, but it is not what I expected.
Is it possible to configure a view to count metered values in particular buckets?

Answer (score 1):

[Histograms](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) in Prometheus are [cumulative histograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Cumulative_histogram), meaning that every bucket contains also count from previous buckets.

Reasoning behind why buckets are cumulative can be found [here](https://www.robustperception.io/why-are-prometheus-histograms-cumulative/). In short: this allows for some buckets to be dropped on ingestion, but still keep histogram functioning.

And `_count` metric is expected to be equal to `{le="+Inf"}` by design:

> the **count** of events that have been observed, exposed as `<basename>_count` (identical to `<basename>_bucket{le="+Inf"}` above)

As far as I know, there is no way to convert Prometheus' histogram metrics to something resembling non-cumulative histograms with one fell swoop: either manually write a query for every bucket like `ping_bucket{le="200"} - ignoring(le) group_left() ping_bucket{le="100"}`, or calculate it outside of Prometheus.

On the other hand, visualization tools, like Grafana, expect this kind of histograms from Prometheus, so this shouldn't be the problem there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. As for visualization in Grafana, I played with my data from Prometheus but didn't manage to achieve the right histogramma view. Could you show me, where I can read about that?